# Grub problem with fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my thinkpad. Everything work but when I boot the PC, the grub command line appears. I can login into the system following the steps described here: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/ .

My problem is that I cannot make those changes persist. I have followed the instructions but they do not work. I have algo generated a boot-repair report, in case you need it: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/T6XQCyX2CF/

To add more information, I executed these commands:

[image]

Just to clarify, I do not have dual boot, before trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 I had Ubuntu 18.04.

Any idea what’s going on?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install. You show using sda5 as msdos which normally should be BIOS boot from a logical partition. UEFI uses gpt partitioning. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: The boot-repair log is from the ppa version.

Comment: You have new UEFI system, but older MBR partitioning. UEFI strongly suggests using gpt, Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot, but Ubuntu will let you install in UEFI mode to MBR. You also have an old BIOS verison of grub in MBR that will not work and an old UEFI boot in p1. UEFI entry looks like it should boot from p2 and UUID in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg in p2 looks like correct UUID. Not sure why not booting. You do have UEFI Secure Boot on, have you tried with UEFI secure boot off?

Comment: Yeah, I have turned it off and made the same steps, but it’s still the same.

Comment: Is there a way to reinstall everything using gpt instead of MBR?

Comment: Why should it boot from ‘p2’? I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed in nvme0n1p5 (maybe that’s not related, I’m quite new to this)

Comment: Your ESP - p2 is your UEFI partition which has the UEFI grub boot files. So UEFI loads grub from p2 and the the grub.cfg in the ESP configfiles or loads the full grub.cfg in your install. Normal install to a blank drive in UEFI mode will default to gpt. If you force conversion to gpt, it will erase drive. You can do that with gparted - With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. You may convert, but have to reinstall grub & edit fstab. Have good backups. Converting from MBR to gpt:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1454252

Answer (score 1):

For old systems, go to BIOS and change the boot order to your Legacy HDD/SSD. Disable UEFI boot order if available.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue after installing 20.04 on an old Dell laptop. Instead of attempting any abstruse solutions, I just hit F12 on bootup and on the BIOS screen select Hard Drive and it boots right up to Ubuntu

Comment: This is a one time solution though; it really doesn't address the OPs concern.  My two cents I would have made this a comment and not an answer.